# How to find a process's pid given its child thread's thread id?

Tags: windows, multithreading, process

Given a thread's thread id, I need to find the pid of the process that owns it. I thought enumerating all threads by toolhelp library and using "th32OwnerProcessID" member of THREADENTRY32 but I'm looking for an easier way (and shorter). I couldn't find a direct api to do this nor could I find an answer in Stack Overflow.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need two WinAPI functions.

1. Get a handle to the thread using [OpenThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684335%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which takes a thread ID as an argument.
2. Get the Process ID using [GetProcessIdOfThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which takes the handle as an argument.

You will need to read the linked documentation about restrictions on their usage before trying to use them.